# 3D similarities and quaternions?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables, quaternions, isometries

As is well-known, in dimension 2, a linear map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a direct similarity if, once we identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ is of the form
$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \quad f(z) = a z + b$$
with $a \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}$. This gives an especially appealing way of describing and parameterizing similarities. By writing $a = r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \theta}$ with $r >0$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, we recover that a similarity is the combination of a rotation (of angle $\theta$), a homothety (of parameter $r$), and a translation (of $b$).

I am curious about possible extension of this result in dimension 3. Of course, there is no three-dimensional space such as the complex numbers. However, it is possible to describe 3D direct similarities in terms of a combination of homotheties (around a certain point, possibly non-zero), rotations (idem), and translations. Since we can represent 3D-rotations with unit-quaternions (see [this nice Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjMuIxRvygQ)), I am wondering if there is a nice comparable relation to $f(z) = az + b$ above in the 3D case.

Comment: One problem is that the rotation action of the quaternions isn't given by $q\mapsto(f_q(z): z\mapsto qz)$ as it is with complex numbers representing 2d rotations, but rather $q\mapsto(f_q(z): z\mapsto q^{-1}zq)$ (possibly with the specific conjugation inverted depending on your conventions).

Comment: This question is, more or less, what led Hamilton to discover the quaternions in the first place.

Comment: What about $v \mapsto qvq^* + u$ where $v$ is a vector quaternion, $u$ is a vector quaternion, and $q$ is a quaternion

Comment: In dimension $4$, any orthogonal transformation is of the form $v\mapsto a\cdot v\cdot b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb S^3\subset H^\times$. This defines the double covering $SU(2)\times SU(2)\to SO(4)$. This generalizes immediately to similarities, the group of which is $\mathbb (H^\times \mathbb H^\times / \big((\lambda,1)\sim (1,\lambda)\big)\ltimes \mathbb H$ acting by $(a,b,x)\circ v = avb + v$. To get to $SO(3)$, restrict to those transformations preserving $\mathbb R^\perp\subset \mathbb H$, which is equivalent to $x\in \mathbb R^\perp,ab\in\mathbb R$, i.e. $b$ is proportional to $\overline a$.

Comment: In terms of matrices, the group of similarity transformations is a subgroup of the group of affine transformations, the latter of which has a matrix representation

Comment: @BertramArnold Shouldn't that be $(a,b,x)\circ v = avb + x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a quaternion whose scalar part is zero a vector quaternion. We shall denote the vector quaternions as $\mathbb R^3$. Given $q = w + xi + yj + zk$, we shall define $q^*$ (called the "conjugate" of $q$) to be $w - xi - yj - zk$.

If $q$ is a unit quaternion, then $v \in \mathbb R^3\mapsto qvq^*$ is a rotation. All rotations about the origin in 3D can be given in this form.

If $q$ is a general (i.e. not necessarily a unit) quaternion, then $v \mapsto qvq^*$ is a rotation followed by a dilation from the origin by $|q|^2$ units.

Finally, add a vector quaternion $x$ to perform a translation. We thus get $v \mapsto qvq^* + x$ as a general form for similarity transformations.

Postscript: This can be generalised to higher dimensions, and some non-Euclidean geometries, using Clifford algebras.

Comment: That's nice, using the "vector quaternions" for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then describing the geometric transformations as exposed does the job. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it obvious that we capture all the direct similarities doing so?

Comment: Yes -- every orientation-preserving similarity is expressible uniquely as an element of SO(n) followed by a scaling followed by a translation.